# Node Express.js server-side rendering doesn't run in a production environment

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

I am currently developing a **React app** with server-side rendering via **Express.js**. On development (NODE_ENV) everything runs smoothly. Once I build my app in a production environment, Node.js fails to run it and there are no verbose errors present:

```
/var/www/html $ node web/assets/js/server_bundle.js
/var/www/html $
```

If I add three *console.log*s in the *server_bundle.js* as so:

```
exports.ids = [0];
console.log(1);
exports.modules = [
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
console.log(2);
"use strict";


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = __webpack_require__(1191);
} else {
  module.exports = __webpack_require__(1192);
}


/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
console.log(3);
"use strict";


Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
```

Only *console.log(1);* gets called:

```
/var/www/html $ node web/assets/js/server_bundle.js
1
/var/www/html $
```

Any ideas how could I debug this ?

Comment: Are any other files output when you run your production build? What's the command you're using to run it? And can you add your webpack config as well?